How can I ensure my SQLite database is initialized before interacting with it in a web app using sql.js and IndexedDB
I'm building a web app using sql.js with WebAssembly to manage a SQLite database in the browser. I'm storing the SQLite database in IndexedDB and need to ensure that the database is loaded and initialized properly before performing any SQL operations.
Here's the current setup:
When the page loads, I try to load the database from IndexedDB or create a new one if it doesn't exist.
I’m using async/await to load the database, but I’m still running into issues where I try to interact with the database before it has been fully initialized.
When I attempt to insert data into the SQLite database or run queries, I sometimes encounter the error: "Database is not initialized."


let db;
const dbName = "db_transactions.db"; // Your specific database name

// Function to load the database from IndexedDB
async function loadDatabaseFromIndexedDB() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open('sqliteDBs', 1); // Open IndexedDB database
    request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
      const dbStore = request.result.createObjectStore('databases', {
        keyPath: 'name'
      });
    };

    request.onsuccess = () => {
      const dbStore = request.result.transaction('databases', 'readwrite').objectStore('databases');
      const getRequest = dbStore.get(dbName);

      getRequest.onsuccess = function() {
        const data = getRequest.result;
        if (data) {
          // Import the saved database binary data
          db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(data.dbBinary));
          resolve(db);
        } else {
          // If no saved database, create a new one
          db = new SQL.Database();
          resolve(db);
        }
      };
      getRequest.onerror = reject;
    };

    request.onerror = reject;
  });
}

// Function to save the database to IndexedDB
async function saveDatabaseToIndexedDB(db) {
  const binaryData = db.export(); // Export the SQLite database to binary format

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open('sqliteDBs', 1); // Open IndexedDB database
    request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
      const dbStore = request.result.createObjectStore('databases', {
        keyPath: 'name'
      });
    };

    request.onsuccess = () => {
      const dbStore = request.result.transaction('databases', 'readwrite').objectStore('databases');
      const putRequest = dbStore.put({
        name: dbName,
        dbBinary: binaryData
      });

      putRequest.onsuccess = resolve;
      putRequest.onerror = reject;
    };

    request.onerror = reject;
  });
}

// Function to initialize the database
async function initializeDatabase() {
  try {
    // Wait for the database to be loaded
    await loadDatabaseFromIndexedDB();
    console.log("Database loaded from IndexedDB or created.");

    // Create table if not exists
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, email TEXT);");
    console.log("Table 'users' created or already exists.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to initialize database:", err);
  }
}

// Wait for the database to initialize before allowing interactions
initializeDatabase().then(() => {
  console.log("Database is initialized.");
});

// Handle form submission
document.getElementById('dataForm').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Ensure db is initialized before proceeding
  if (!db) {
    console.error("Database is not initialized.");
    return;
  }

  // Get form data
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

  // Insert data into the SQLite database
  try {
    db.run("INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?, ?);", [name, email]);

    // Save the updated database to IndexedDB
    await saveDatabaseToIndexedDB(db);
    console.log('Database saved to IndexedDB.');

    // Retrieve and display data from the database
    const result = db.exec("SELECT * FROM users;");
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error while inserting data or saving database:", err);
  }
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SQLite with WebAssembly</title>
  <!-- Correct inclusion of sql.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sql.js@1.6.0/dist/sql-wasm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>SQLite with WebAssembly (Persistent Database)</h1>

  <form id="dataForm">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <h2>Database Output</h2>
  <pre id="output"></pre>


</body>

</html>




When you declare a function async you don't need to use return new Promise(), since it already returns a promise.

Conversely, if you're using an explicit Promise so you can call resolve() in a callback, don't declare the function async.

Which part of the code is trying to interact with the DB before it's initialized? You don't save to the DB until the user submits the form, it's unlikely they can do that before it's initialized.

If you want to be really safe, move the code that adds the submit listener into the initializeDatabase().then() code.

I still don't see anything in the database

Are you getting the message Database loaded from IndexedDB or created?

Yes i see it in the console

I don't see how you can get that message and still get the message saying it's not loaded.

await loadDatabaseFromIndexedDB(); will not complete until it calls resolve(db), and it assigns to db before each of those. So there's no way for if (!db) to succeed after that.
